# Visual Studio Github new code automate publish

Tags: visual-studio, github, build-automation

I have a Visual Studio  (`Asp.net mvc`) project that is getting big.

The code is in GitHub and all developers have their own branch where they work and once they finish something they commit to their branch and then they merge into the main repository.

We are using VS 2017 Community version.

It's time to do automate publishes and I would like to know from other how they manage it using `GitHub`.

The nice to have would be like every new version into the main `GitHub` repository should automaticly published to `QA` server.

Does anyone know if there is a free tool, or a way to do this process automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to consider...

TravisCI and CodeCI are two of the popular services linked into Github that will automate your pushes many popular destinations. You can see details on that [here](https://github.com/marketplace).

Online hosting services, such as Azure App Services, AppHarbor, and GearHost all have their own custom integrations, which typically rely upon a git hook to detect when a source code change has occurred and deploy the latest update into your hosted site.

Certain integration services, such as DeployBot, can integrate with different source control and hosting platforms and handle this integration for you.

Finally, if you want to deploy locally to your own resources you could setup your own server using [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu), which is the automated deployment service Azure is based on.

Hopefully something in here will meet your needs. There are plenty more resources out there you could search for as well.

Comment: I think DeployBot will work, because i have a dedicated server and then via SFTP will be great. Appreciate it